# Specify output window for elisp command

Tags: emacs, elisp

In a script that sets up my Emacs workspace, I use the command

```
(shell (format "%s Interactive" name))
```

four times, to start four interactive shells with different names and uses. The problem is that each shell loads in an arbitrary window within Emacs. I want to control the mapping between shells and windows. In particular, I have four quadrants (created by `split-window-vertically` and `split-window-horizontally`) and I want to define the shells that go in each quadrant. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you just cycle through the windows and switch each to a different shell buffer?

Comment: Maybe...what would be the elisp to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use [`display-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Displaying-Buffers.html) on the buffer objects returned by the [`shell`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html) commands.

Alternatively, you can use [`set-window-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffers-and-Windows.html) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good way to do could be with something like:

```
(defun my-shell-display-buffer (buffer alist)
  (let ((name (cdr (assq 'my-name alist))))
    ..display according to name...)))

(dolist (name '(...)
  (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action
         `(my-shell-display-buffer (my-name . ,name))))
    (shell (format "%s Interactive" name)))
```

An alternative is to do

```
(push `(" Interactive\\'" my-shell-display-buffer)
      display-buffer-alist)
```

and then `my-shell-display-buffer` can extract the shell's name via some other mean, e.g. from the buffer's name.